# How would I databind a Paragraph to a TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, textblock, paragraph

How would I take a `Paragraph` object and databind them to the TextBlock for use in a DataTemplate?
A plain bind does nothing, just a `ToString()` of the Paragraph object.

The InLines property would let me add a list of TextRun's that make up the Paragraph manually, but that can't be bound to and I could really do with a binding based solution.

*Edited question to focus on what I really need to do.*

Comment: I edited my answer - does that solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using a nested ItemsControl.  Unfortunately, it will make one TextBlock per Inline instead of putting the whole Paragraph into one TextBlock:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <FlowDocument x:Key="document">
            <Paragraph><Run xml:space="preserve">This is the first paragraph.  </Run><Run>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</Run></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph><Run xml:space="preserve">This is the second paragraph.  </Run><Run>Two driven jocks help fax my big quiz.</Run></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph><Run xml:space="preserve">This is the third paragraph.  </Run><Run>Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow!</Run></Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Inlines}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks, Source={StaticResource document}}"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want one Paragraph per element you should probably do as suggested and use a read-only RichTextBox, or [do what this person did and derive from TextBlock](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b36a413f-e57e-4b60-bc08-bcf1f9c8bfd5/) so that the Inlines property can be bound.

Comment: I went with the derive from TextBlock method as suggested in that forum post as that seems to of worked the best. +1 to Andy and joshperry for similar answers that would of worked if I didn't need multiple Inlines. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need and solved it along the lines of Andy's answer... I created a BindableTextBlock:

```
class BindableTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public Inline BoundInline
    {
        get { return (Inline)GetValue(BoundInlineProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BoundInlineProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundInlineProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundInline", typeof(Inline), typeof(BindableTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata((PropertyChangedCallback)((d, e) => { ((BindableTextBlock)d).Inlines.Clear(); ((BindableTextBlock)d).Inlines.Add(e.NewValue as Inline); })));
}
```

Then in my XAML I can bind to the BoundInline dependency property:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TempTemplate">
        <t:BindableTextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" BoundInline="{Binding Path=TextInlines}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

The one drawback to this is that you can only bind a single root Inline to the textblock, which worked fine for my situation as my content is all wrapped in a top-level Span.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can bind a Paragraph directly to a TextBlock's inlines. However, I was able to find the class [BindableRun](http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/) that lets you bind to the Run's Text property. Would that work for you instead?

EDIT: Modified my answer to reflect the edited question.

Comment: But how would I display that Paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your own DataTemplate for Paragraph objects that wraps each one in its own FlowDocument, which is then presented via a RichTextBox (readonly, of course)

Comment: All of those objects come with large amounts of built in functionality which make them rather large. I'd like to keep things small.

Comment: With a VirtualizingStackPanel, only the few visible blocks are actually present in memory, if I understood the concept of virtualizing panels correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem and answered it in a similar way to joshperry, sub-classing TextBlock to make the inlines Bindable. In addition I wrote a convertor between a String of xaml markup and an InlineCollection.

[How to bind a TextBlock to a resource containing formatted text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565885/how-to-bind-a-textblock-to-a-resource-containing-formatted-text)